# Mesh.CombineMeshes ignores given meshes and creates a cubic one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

[image]

This is what im doing in order to combine the cubes:

```
MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];
int i = 0;

while (i < meshFilters.Length) {
    combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
    combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
    meshFilters[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    i++;
}

var meshFilter = transform.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
var mesh = new Mesh();
mesh.CombineMeshes(combine, true, false);
meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
transform.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh;
```

Why is this happening?
I basically want to merge 2 meshes to generate then a MeshCollider

Hierarchy is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can merge colliders, only meshes. So you shouldn't deactivate the gameobjects.

Comment: @Lestat I updated the images to correctly show the problem :)

Comment: What's the problem? You seem to have modified the question again...Is this mesh combine problem or collider combine problem?

Comment: Sorry for the changes. The problem is the MeshCombine result as you can see in the images now. I was talking about colliders, because i only use the  resulting mesh, to then generate a meshcollider with L form. But if the MeshCombine result is wrong, the collider will too be wrong

Comment: Please add Hierarchy screenshot that shows the object this script is attached to and the objects you want to combine. Also, are these also box colliders too?

Comment: Screenshot added, they were, now they are not. I started to randomly change MeshCombine parameters and L mesh appears if i set them to mesh.CombineMeshes(combine, true, true);
The generated MeshCollider doesnt follow the L design: https://imgur.com/a/Bu8z1

Comment: Your block/child objects are inactive so `GetComponentsInChildren` can't find them...This statement is based on your screenshot

Comment: I took the screenshot ingame, so the script already got executed and disabled them :) (check the while, has a setActive(false))

Comment: Lol, my bad. The first screenshot is actually the result you get? You are trying to combine the two Block objects under the CombineChilds object?

Comment: Yes & yes. The generated mesh is then set on parent "CombineChilds"

Comment: I just tried this and got totally different result. The object is combining but they are being moved to different location after the combining. I was able to see them in another place from the Scene view by pressing F.

Comment: Displacement is normal when MeshCombining (unity things), if you place a Meshcollider to that object, does it have L form too? Or looks like: https://imgur.com/a/Bu8z1

Comment: I did not use MeshCollider. I simply used Cube with its default BoxCollider and it works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156600/discussion-between-frakydale-and-programmer).